# Convert WinForm App to WPF ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am converting a simple WinForm app to WPF using MVVM pattern. My partiality implemented view-model code is as below. I am stuck in `showPath(string path)` and `addFile(string file)` method because they are using WPF control. How I can overcome this problem?

```
class DirectorySearchModel
{
    /*-- invoke on UI thread --------------------------------*/

    void showPath(string path)
    {
        //textBlock1.Text = path;
        //return path;
    }
    /*-- invoke on UI thread --------------------------------*/

    void addFile(string file)
    {
        //listBox1.Items.Add(file);
    }
    /*-- recursive search for files matching pattern --------*/

    void Search(string path, string pattern)
    {
        /* called on asynch delegate's thread */
        if (System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
            showPath(path);
        else
            System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(
              new Action<string>(showPath), DispatcherPriority.Background, new string[] { path }
            );
        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(path, pattern);
        foreach (string file in files)
        {
            if (System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
                addFile(file);
            else
                System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action<string>(addFile), DispatcherPriority.Background,
                  new string[] { file }
                );
        }
        string[] dirs = System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(path);
        foreach (string dir in dirs)
            Search(dir, pattern);
    }



}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How I can overcome this problem

You would make two properties - an `ObservableCollection<string>` for the filenames (what was `listBox1`) and a `string` (which also raises `PropertyChanged` on set) for the path (what was `textBlock1`).  The view would then bind to these properties.

These methods just need to set the path and add to the collection, and the view will update automatically.

Comment: I have made changes as per your suggestion but I am getting error in this line System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(
                  new Action(ShowPath), DispatcherPriority.Background, new string[] { path }

Comment: I'd write it as:              `Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => this.addFile(file)), DispatcherPriority.Background);`